# How to overcome nested for loop to achieve a linear time complexity?

Tags: python, for-loop, time-complexity

First of all this code compare the two dictionaries and puts it into one bigger dictionary. 
1. If it has the same key, put the value from two dictionaries into one key. 
2. If it has a similar key (e.g. banana & banan4), also put the value from two dictionaries into one key and remove it. 
3. Lastly, if it has a different value than put the value according to the key of its original dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

dict1 = {'apple' : 'g1', 'banana' : 'g2', 'mango' : 'g3'}
dict2 = {'apple' : 'a3', 'banana' : 'a4', 'grapes' : 'a1', 'pear' : 'a2', 'banan4' : 'a5'}

merged = {}
blocked_tuple = (dict1, dict2)
threshold = 59

for new_dict in blocked_tuple:
    for key in new_dict:
        flag = True
        if key in merged:
            merged[key].append(new_dict[key])
            flag = False
        else:
            merged[key] = [new_dict[key]]
        while flag:
            try:
                for i in merged:
                    distance = fuzz.token_set_ratio(key, i)
                    if (distance > threshold) and (distance != 100):
                        merged.pop(key)
                        merged[i].append(new_dict[key])
                        flag = False
                    else: flag = False
            except: pass

print(merged)
```

This code will output:

```
{'apple': ['g1', 'a3'], 'banana': ['g2', 'a4', 'a5'], 'mango': ['g3'], 'grapes': ['a1'], 'pear': ['a2']}
```

Which is exactly what I wanted. However, on a much bigger dictionary, this program would continuously run.
Is there any way to create a new function with linear time complexity with the same output as I have shown above

Comment: You should explain what the code does, so that people don't have to study the code to find out what is happening, and how the output is achieved.

Comment: Based on the question it is clear that you need to compare all the keys of the dictionaries (intra and inter dict) with fuzz.  You cannot scape `(len(A)+len(B))^2` coplexity unless the variations are known.

Answer (score 0):

you can somewhat tackle this by sorting first based on some heuristic.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
dict1 = {'apple' : 'g1', 'banana' : 'g2', 'mango' : 'g3'}
dict2 = {'apple' : 'a3', 'banana' : 'a4', 'grapes' : 'a1', 'pear' : 'a2', 'banan4' : 'a5'}

merged = {}
threshold = 59
# the heuristic being sorted strings may be closer together
# this is not a perfect solution
keys = sorted(set(dict1.keys()).union(dict2.keys()))
# another heuristic could be you can sort on the freq dict. using Counter.
key_groups = []
i = 0
# you can try to group keys before merging
while i < len(keys) - 1:
    j = i
    dist = lambda :fuzz.token_set_ratio(keys[i], keys[j])
    while dist() > 59:
        j+=1
    key_groups.append(set(keys[i:j]))
    i=j
print(key_groups)
for key_group in key_groups:
    key = key_group.pop()
    val_set = merged.setdefault(key, set())
    for key in key_group.union([key]):
        if key in dict1:
            val_set.add(dict1[key])
        if key in dict2:
            val_set.add(dict2[key])
print(merged)
```

```sh
╰─➤  python3 snippet.py
[{'apple'}, {'banana', 'banan4'}, {'grapes'}, {'mango'}]
{'apple': {'g1', 'a3'}, 'banana': {'g2', 'a5', 'a4'}, 'grapes': {'a1'}, 'mango': {'g3'}}
```

This can bring it down nlogn in practice, if the keys play nice with your sorting heuristic